# Bug in Camel 2.13.2 Release-Bud Id 7544

Tags: apache-camel

The XSD allows to specify `customId="true" id="foo"` in the route elements. But when reading the route using Spring you get a parse error in Spring. I can't able to understand this bug. Can you please clarify me?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `customId` but only `id`.

The customId is for internal usage when updating routes from XML that the id is auto assigned or assigned by the end user.